# What is the purpose of the scales factor in Faster Rcnn Box Coder?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm using the object detection api and tuning the parameters for a SSD task. My question refers to the box coder at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/box_coders/faster_rcnn_box_coder.py. 
Why setting these scales factors to [10,10,5,5]? The original paper does not explain it. I suspect that it has to do either assigning a different weight to the 4 components of location error (tx, ty, tw, th) or  with some numerical stability issue, but I would like to have a confirmation. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I find the answer here https://leimao.github.io/blog/Bounding-Box-Encoding-Decoding/, where the variables are used as some sort of Representation Encoding With Variance. The question was also the subject of this issue https://github.com/rykov8/ssd_keras/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

The network predicts changes for each anchor box. That is, for each anchor block, it predicts an offset for x, y position and width, height.

a short description of these parameters can be found, for example to link:
https://medium.com/@smallfishbigsea/understand-ssd-and-implement-your-own-caa3232cd6ad
https://lambdalabs.com/blog/how-to-implement-ssd-object-detection-in-tensorflow/

Comment: Thanks but I don´t see your answer as valid. The original paper of FRCNN is here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf and you can see that there is no trace of this scale values [10 10 5 5]. The comment in the code says "scale_factors: List of 4 positive scalars to scale ty, tx, th and tw. For Faster RCNN, the open-source implementation recommends using [10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 5.0]. [...] Scales location targets as used in paper for joint training"